# How to add an ORM into an existing project

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, refactoring

I have a client who has a website I work on. Basic LAMP architecture, but quite large. I have successfully lobbied to get them to pay me to start refactoring it, and one of the first things I am going to do is to split out a proper database layer, where at the moment there are only scattered SQL queries all over a completely procedural codebase (the only objects are made by instanciating stdClass() and adding properties to it.)

What I would like to do is create objects that map to the database, so I can query them and have the SQL made for me behind the scenes. So I need an ORM. I have read the docs on Doctrine 2 and I like it.

Is it possible to do this, given that the database itself is as far as I can tell properly relational, or do all ORMs insist on their own table names?

Should I roll my own?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can also reverse engine it:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/tools.html#convert-mapping-information